# Error: read ECONNRESET for DynamoDB put request using DocumentClient

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a new item in my DynamoDB table using the put function for DocumentClient, but am getting an error that references ECONNRESET.  When others have referenced ECONNRESET on stack overflow, it seems that it might be a proxy issue for them.  I am not sure how I would go about debugging this though.

Here are the docs I have been using:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/dynamodb-from-js-lambda/q/platform/js/

Here is the code

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'})

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

export const createItem = async (tableName, item) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: item
  };
  console.log(params);
  try {
    await docClient.put(params).promise();
    console.log("Success");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

and here is the error I get

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
  errno: -4077
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  syscall: 'read',
  time: 2021-09-25T12:30:23.577z,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true
}
```

Screenshot of code and terminal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4JvP.png

Comment: Where is your code running and what is the network configuration of that host?

Comment: @peter I figured it out.  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Somebody helped me out.  I was using a company CLI via a proxy to do manual local testing.  I had to use this command in the CLI `pc login aws --shared-credentials` which is pretty specific to where I work.

I also had to include this code:

```
const proxy = require('proxy-agent');
AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: {
    agent: proxy(process.env.HTTP_PROXY)
  }
});
```